# Swift: reflection of protocol variables

Tags: swift, mirroring

I have a protocol with some { get } and { get set } variables and extension, where I set the former ones, and when initializing the class - to set the latter ones too. And I'd like to return all of them in a dictionary, i.e.:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var id: Int { get }
    var name: String { get set }
    var isItTrue: Bool { get }
}

extension SomeProtocol where Self: SomeClass {
    var id: Int { return 1 }
    var isItTrue: Bool { return true }

    func classProps() {
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        let mirrorSelf = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for mirrorChild in mirrorSelf.children { print(mirrorChild.label) }
    }
}

class SomeClass {
// just a class, nothing special
}

class MirrorMe: SomeClass, SomeProtocol {
    var name: String = "Some name"
}

class MirrorMirrorOnTheWall {
    func talkToTheMirror() {
        let mirrorThis = MirrorMe()
        mirrorThis.classProps() // returns only "name" property
    }
}
```

as I wrote in the comment, `classProps` returns only the protocol variable I set in the subclass. How can I include both **id** and **isItTrue** in the Mirror's children as well?

p.s. sorry for the crappy example, this is just a quick example :)

Comment: Dude, what version of XCode are you using? :) P.S. I have some partial answer of my question: when I break after the initialization of the subclass, I don't see the protocol variables in the debugger, I can print them via ```po something``` , but cannot see them in the Variable tree in XCode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Computed properties are not represented in the runtime introspection provided by `Mirror`

From [the Language Reference - Mirror struct](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Mirror_Structure/index.html) (emphasis added by me)

> Representation of the sub-structure and optional "display style" of
>   any arbitrary **subject instance**.
>
> Describes the parts---such as **stored properties**, collection elements,
>   tuple elements, or the active enumeration case---*that make up a
>   particular instance*. May also supply a "display style" property that
>   suggests how this structure might be rendered.

The properties `id` (`int`) and `isItTrue` (`bool`) are available to instances of `MirrorMe`, but *only as computed properties*, as `MirrorMe` does not implement these as stored properties, but rather, make use of the default implementation of them as computed properties from `extension SomeProtocol where Self: SomeClass { ... }`. Hence, the computed properties `id` and `isItTrue` of `MirrorMe` are not contained in the sub-structure representation of `MirrorMe` instances, as provided by runtime introspection using `Mirror`.

We can verify this clearly in a more minimal example:

```
class Foo {
    // a stored property
    let representedInIntrospection = 0

    // a computed property
    var notRepresented: Int { return representedInIntrospection }
}

Mirror(reflecting: Foo())
    .children
    .forEach { print($0.label, $0.value) }
        /* Optional("representedInIntrospection") 0 */
```

To summarize: properties blueprinted in a protocol, with or without an associated default implementation, can never be stored properties on their own (default implementations of blueprinted properties may naturally only contain computed properties). This means that the only properties that are *explicitly declared as stored properties* in the class/struct that conforms to your protocol will show up when applying runtime introspection of an instance of such a class/struct.

Finally, you never mention the reason as for why you want a dictionary of the stored properties of a class instance, but take care if making use of this a production purpose. Generally, runtime introspection in a type safe language as Swift should only be used for diagnostics and debugging, even if it allows to be used in runtime hacks (e.g. with KVO for classes inheriting from `NSObject`).

Comment: ```var id: Int { get set }``` is because of many edits of the code. I corrected it. And thanks for your answer. I thought the value assigning in the extension will make an impact, but whatever :) I'll add the computed properties manually to the dict. Thank you all!

Comment: @user3352185 happy to help! Just make sure to take note of the final paragraph in my answer (beware of runtime introspection hacks!)